# Can run terraform commands on files generated via terraformer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have tf files generated via terraformer and when i run 'terraform plan/refresh' it gives me a bunch of errors for examle:

```
    Error: Invalid combination of arguments

  on instance.tf line 400, in resource "aws_instance" "worker-node":
 400:     id   = "lt-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

"launch_template.0.id": only one of
`launch_template.0.id,launch_template.0.name` can be specified, but
`launch_template.0.id,launch_template.0.name` were specified.


Error: Invalid combination of arguments

  on instance.tf line 401, in resource "aws_instance" "worker-node":
 401:     name = "eksctl-workernode"

"launch_template.0.name": only one of
`launch_template.0.id,launch_template.0.name` can be specified, but
`launch_template.0.id,launch_template.0.name` were specified.
```

This is just regarding the EC2's and for every other service it gives a different error.THe instances causing the error are EKS nodes.

Comment: What is the code that produces the error?

Comment: How can i see the error code?

Answer (score 0):

Your Launch Template variables dont seem right. You probably have some code for worker node which needs to be rectified. Are you trying to use [EKS node groups?](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_node_group)

Comment: no. I solved it though. apperently in launch template there are to configurations which when are written under "lauch template"{} they causing an error. so i deleted the lauch template name and left just the id and terraform plan/refresh worked.

Answer (score 0):

Community answer from comments:

> There was configurations in the launch template. Which caused an error being written under `launch template{}`
>
> So I deleted the `launch template` name and left just the `id`.
>
> And then `terraform plan`/`apply` worked